# Drawing Graphic at street layer/level only

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, graphics

I am new to ArcGIS JavaScript API and would like some help. I have a scenario where a user has to draw a graphic, mainly a polyline and some points on a map. To avoid confusion I want to limit the user to zoom in to street level prior to start drawing.

What I am trying to achieve here is when the user clicks on the locality he/she wants to draw on, on the click even the map zooms in to street layers.

I have been looking around but can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you should be listening to the map's '[click](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#event-click)' event and calling a method like [centerAndZoom()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerandzoom), passing in the mapPoint that is returned by the event and whatever zoom level you think would be appropriate.